# Es wurde "im Personenstandsamt" oder "beim Personenstandsamt" eingetragen?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Die Angaben des Geborenen wurden  am 07.12.2009 im Geburtsregister Nr.: 1 unter der Nummer: 1712 **im Personenstandsamt** eingetragen.

Die Angaben des Geborenen wurden  am 07.12.2009 im Geburtsregister Nr.: 1 unter der Nummer: 1712  **beim Personenstandsamt** eingetragen.

Is the meaning changed by using "beim Amt" instead of "im Amt"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both *im* and *beim*, but if you used *im*, people would assume you are referring to the building the institution is in rather than the institution itself.

It's the same with *im Geburtsregister*. That means it was actually written into a file. If you wrote *beim Geburtsregister* instead, people would assume there's an office inside the *Personenstandsamt* which is named *Geburtsregister*.

Answer (score 2):

First, the office handling the "Personenstandswesen", maintaining the "Personenstandsregister", issuing "Personenstandsurkunden" is commonly called [Standesamt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standesamt). I wouldn't rule out that some municipality somewhere uses the term "Personenstandsamt", but that would be the exception to the rule.

Regarding your questiong, there's a little difference in nuance. "Im Amt" puts the focus a bit more on the physical office, on the building it resides in. "Beim Amt" puts the focus a bit more on the office as an abstract institution.